# Vectorizing a sequence \$x_{i+1} = f(x_i)\$ with NumPy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I would like to populate a NumPy array with "accumulated" results from a custom function.

Currently, my code is:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x, mu):
    return mu * x * (1 - x)

def populate(x0, mu, n):
    s = np.zeros(n)
    x = x0
    for i in range(n):
        s[i], x = x, f(x, mu)
    return s
```

It does not take advantage of the vectorization performance of NumPy.

Is there any way to improve the speed of creating arrays like this?

Comment: @Graipher Are you sere about that? I tested it and `s[0] == x0`.

Comment: You are right, I misread the swap.

Comment: You might be able to gain a tiny bit of speed by calculating the composition of f with itself say 4 times, then call that on four values at the same time. It wastes a bunch of work but might end up being faster. f(f(x)) = r(rx(1-x))(1-rx(1-x)), do the algebra, come up with a polynomial. Sort of like unrolling the loop.

Comment: @Snowbody that's an interesting idea. You might get different answers based on rounding errors, thought.

Comment: Getting way off topic but... There's actually a theorem for the logistic map that states that starting at $x_0$ and iterating the map with rounding errors will yield a path where every point $x_i$ is within $delta$ of the corresponding point $x'_n$ another path that starts at $x'_0 = x_0+epsilon$ and is iterated exactly. The mapping between $epsilon$ and $delta$ is a function of the rounding error.

Comment: I did the algebra. There's 69 terms (constant * power of mu * power of x) that have to be added up for the 4x-composition. There's no way this is faster, even if you get the full speedup. I conclude this is not parallelizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't vectorize this. Repeated application of \$x_i = \mu x_{i-1} (1-x_{i-1})\$ is [chaotic](http://www.ies-math.com/math/java/misc/chaosa/chaosa.html).

Comment: Yes, I realize that trying to "vectorize" this kind of function makes no sense. But I wonder if there is a way to avoid the Python loop and use only Numpy features.

Answer (score 4):

As the others said it is not vectorizable via numpy since each iteration depends on the previous application of the function.

However, if you need speed, you can always use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) to JIT-compile the whole python loop into machine code...

Time to run populate(0.2,0.3,1000000), for three iterations:

Without numba

```
0.749
0.766
0.727
```

With numba

```
0.356
0.010
0.007
```

The first iteration is not much faster than original python, as it includes the compilation to machine code (I presume some libraries have to be loaded, etc). The others are a lot faster... 10ms versus 750ms in pure python...

Comment: Indeed, I thought that there might be an optimized way to do that in Numpy, but it seems not.

Comment: I made a little benchmark, considering adding numba to your program takes 2 lines of code, a 75x speedup on this function aint too bad!

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bad thing to have your code take up more space!

```
s[i] = x
x = f(x, mu)
```

is a lot easier to read than

```
s[i], x = x, f(x, mu)
```

So overall that would be

```
import numpy as np  
def f(x, mu):
    return mu * x * (1 - x)

def populate(x0, mu, n):
    s = np.zeros(n)
    x = x0
    for i in range(n):
        s[i] = x
        x = f(x, mu)
    return s
```

Comment: I am not sure about your updated `populate()` function, it does not add the calculated values to `s`.

Comment: I thought it did, have you run it?

Comment: Yes, it returns an array full of `0`. Look at the code: it never modifies `s`.

Comment: But it modifies num which is a part of s

Comment: But `num` is just a `float`, so "modifying" it is actually just assigning a new value to the variable `num`.

Comment: Okay, I am reasonably new to Stack Exchange and don't know if I should edit my answer to just have the useful bit to prevent confusion in the future

Comment: Yes, I think you should edit, because currently it does not seem to work as the initial `populate()`.